# Why doesn't the same Windows font look the same when migrating to emacs 26.1?

Tags: microsoft-windows, fonts, emacs26

I'm trying to migrate from emacs 24.5 to emacs 26.1. I installed 26.1 and running both with the same config files. I took several tries and fixing small things in the config, for emacs 26.1 to start without errors.

However, the font setting has problems. It is set by a frame parameter in initial-frame-alist:

```
(font . "-outline-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-mono-18-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1")
```

It works fine in 24.5. but in 26.1 the exact same font setting results in smaller font (emacs 26.1 below):

[image]

Why is that?

According to describe font the same font and size is used, only the font version is different for some reason:

emacs 24:

```
name (opened by): -outline-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-mono-18-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1
       full name: Consolas-13.5
            size: 18
          height: 22
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0
```

emacs 26.1:

```
name (opened by): -outline-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-mono-18-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1
       full name: Consolas-11.0
            size: 18
          height: 22
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0
  default-ascent: 17
          ascent: 17
         descent:  5
   average-width: 10
     space-width: 10
       max-width: 20
```

Why emacs 26 finds a different version of the same font in the first place?

Comment: Why "Consolas-13.5" vs "Consolas-11.0" ?

Comment: I asked the same at the very end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has changed on its way from 24 to 26 its mind on what the forced size "18" means in your  initial-frame-alist.

In your examination the size is 18 in both cases, and the 26 screenshot looks a bit more like it would be 18 pixels.

I use `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Anonymous Pro-12"))` to setup my emacsframe and I guess if you use `"Consolas-13.5"` in the font value, your display will look the same in both versions - minus the possibility that the fractional part might be interpreted different.

[Window FAQ on fonts from the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html#Font-names)

Comment: Setting the font to "Consolas-13.5" is slightly better, the font is bigger, but still not as big as with emacs 24. I don't know why that is, but as a quick fix I guess I can set a bigger font size for emacs 26 if the same font setting cannot be used for both.